# Adding hover delay to drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a delay to a jquery drop down menu. I've gotten the delay to work correctly. But it's adding the delay to all of the drop down menus. Here is the code I'm using:

```
var timer;
var delay = 1000;
$('.header__nav-main-list > li', '#header').hover(function() {
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $('.header__nav-main-list > li', '#header').children(".header__nav-sub-list").show();
        $('.header__nav-main-list > li', '#header').addClass("is-open");
    }, delay);
}, function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(".header__nav-sub-list").hide();
    $('.header__nav-main-list > li').removeClass("is-open");
});
```

Instead I want it to only add the delay to the nav item I am hovering over so I tried something like this below, but instead it can't determine what "this" is referring to.

```
var timer;
var delay = 1000;
$('.header__nav-main-list > li', '#header').hover(function() {
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).children(".header__nav-sub-list").show();
        $(this).addClass("is-open");
    }, delay);
}, function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(".header__nav-sub-list").hide();
    $('.header__nav-main-list > li').removeClass("is-open");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed you cannot use $(this), but it should work like that:

```
var timer;
var delay = 1000;
$('.header__nav-main-list > li', '#header').hover(function(event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        $this.children(".header__nav-sub-list").show();
        $this.addClass("is-open");
    }, delay);
}, function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(".header__nav-sub-list").hide(0);
    $('.header__nav-main-list > li').removeClass("is-open");
});
```

Comment: thanks! I actually tried something similar to this but was writing wrong. I was instead writing $($this).children(...).show();

Comment: you're welcome... your code might have worked if you had first declared and assigned `$this`  eg. `var $this = this`  (or even `var $this = $(this)` )